# Como conectar un bloque de volumen a un pods en kubernets. En OCI

Tags: kubernetes, devops

Necesito conectar un bloque de volumen a un pod existente de kubernets. como puedo realizar sin afectar la producción

He creado un volumen sin existe en la creación del yaml

Comment: explica un poco mas problema, que has intentado hacer

Comment: 1. Los datos que tienes en el pod de producción se pueden deshechar? 2. El pod está en un deployment? Si ambos son si entonces si se puede.